# Fastpass accessibility extension for android

Tags: accessibility-insights

I have come across Fastrpass accessibility extension for android. does this support testing on mobile browsers (RWD) and tablet browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I'm not 100% clear which extension you're asking about. If you're asking about [Accessibility Insights for Android](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/android/overview/), then it will run on *any* Android application. Unlike [Accessibility Insights for Web](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/accessibility-insights-fo/pbjjkligggfmakdaogkfomddhfmpjeni), which operates as a browser extension and accesses the browser's DOM directly, Accessibility Insights for Android leverages Android's built-in accessibility support.

--Dave Tryon
(Accessibility Insights team)